# Writing a tex file with a specific font

Tags: fonts

In many online notes or books on Latex, the fonts I found were using commands `\sf`, `\sc`, and `\rm`. Beyond this, I have no idea of other fonts. Here, I was trying to type a file in the following type of fonts.

> [image]

How can I type in Latex with *this* type of font?

In the usual typing of my documents, the fonts look like this:

> [image]

Comment: you dont know what is the font (it name) you want to use ?

Comment: The only way you can 'type in Latex' with a certain font is for you (or the web service you are using) to have the font installed. So you need to (1) figure out what font(s) you want to use, and (2) ensure they are installed in a way that LaTeX can use them. I think, however, you may still need to figure out (1)....

Comment: Please see the FAQ [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919/5764)

Comment: I saw the fonts in a copy of exercise sheet distributed to us, and then came to question, what this font is? (The distributor was some secretary and he had no idea of that; I couldn't find the type of font)

Comment: Go to [TeX font catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/), then select some font as [Garamond](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/garamond/) and try to use as explained for each font.

Comment: this looks very like the default font, computer modern, and there is no special font command for the math letters and symbols; they are simply typed as math, probably between `$...$` or `\( ... \)`.  you need some basic introduction to tex input.  there are some good suggestions here" [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/579)

Comment: And do not use `\sf`, `\sc`, `\bf`, `\rm` etc. in LaTeX. They are 20+ years obsolete.